# adding this as parameter to function in jquery

Tags: jquery

In my page I need to give my current variable as parameter to the function AjaxLoader and then add class selected to it. 
However when I pass it as parameter it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? 
My code is below.

```
$('a').click(function() {

   var current = $(this).find('td');
   current.addClass("selected");
   AjaxLoader(current);

}

function AjaxLoader(current){

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test1.php",
   success: function(response) {
    //this is what I want to do
   current.addClass("selected");
     }


   })


 }
```

Comment: What errors did you receive? Have you tried logging `current` to the console before you add the class to see what's in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you may use context member of ajax argument

```
$.ajax( {..., context: current, success: function () { $(this) // current
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your functions. Also you muse define the function before you use it.

```
function AjaxLoader(current){

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "test1.php",
       success: function(response) {
           //this is what I want to do
           current.addClass("selected");
           }
   });
}

$('a').click(function() {

   var current = $(this).find('td');
   current.addClass("selected");
   AjaxLoader(current);

});
```

Comment: The `AjaxLoader` function was already closed. You have added an extra, invalid `);`. Well spotted on the `click` event handler though.

Comment: Cool. However, you don't have to declare the function before you use it since function declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they are declared. It does make the code easier to follow though.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely you have a table inside an A tag.
You probably want `closest()` or `parent()` instead of `find()` to get the td that contains the A tag. `find()` looks for descendents of an element

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

```
$('a').click(function() {

   var current = $(this).closest('td');
   current.addClass("selected");
   AjaxLoader(current);

});

function AjaxLoader(current){

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "test1.php",
       success: function(response) {
       //this is what I want to do
       current.addClass("selected");
       }
   });
};
```